# Determining if it is a Function, based on Domain and Co-domain

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\,, where $ f(n)= \begin{cases} 
x^2&\text{if}\, x\leq 2\\ x-1&\text{if}\, 
x\geq 4\\ \end{cases}

I am not sure if this is a function, given the domain and co-domain.

I understand that the domain and co-domain are both real numbers. However, my confusion is whether ALL real numbers in the domain have to be considered.

Because when x = 3, f(3) is undefined, but that's not considered in the domain of the piecewise function. So do I ignore when x = 3, and only consider the domain of the piecewise function where x $\le$ 2 and x $\ge$ 4, in which case it f(n) is a function? Or do I have to consider ALL real numbers of the domain, where x = 3 is undefined, and therefore f(n) is NOT a function?

Thank you!

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb R$ as per first line. The definition of $f$ given is insufficient to comment whether it's a function or not.

Comment: Also, do not write $n$ on the left side and $x$ on the right side.

Comment: @An_Elepant Why is it insufficient?